# Using free on a C struct

Tags: c, malloc

I have a simple Linked List node as follows

```
typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    struct ListElement *next;           
} node;
```

Also I have a node create and delete function as follows:

```
void createNode(void *data){
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    //assign data to data and initialize pointer to NULL
}

void deleteNode(List *list, Node *node){
    //Take care of the next pointer
    free(node);
}
```

When I free the node, do I have to delete the members of the struct (data and next pointer) as well? Since I am not using malloc specifically for the members, but only for the entire struct? If so then how do I do it? Will all the members of the node be placed on the heap, and the stack will not be used at all?

Comment: Basically every `malloc()` should have a corresponding `free()`.

Comment: I am not specifically using malloc to assign the data variable. So is it placed on the stack then?

Comment: It doesn't matter where `data` is located. If it wasn't obtained with `malloc()` you don't `free()` it. It can be on the stack, on registers, on swap disk, ...

Comment: `struct node` has a `next` member that points, not to another `struct node`, but to a `struct ListElement` (which you haven't shown us). That seems odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The ultimate rule: you `free()` exactly the same number of times you `malloc()`** (or `calloc()`, or...)

So:

I. If the `data` points to something allocated by these functions, then yes, you need to do so.

II. `node->next` is to be freed of course (assuming you are freeing the entire list), so you need to free it anyway, **but only after you have taken care of the next element.**

An iterative solution:

```
void free_list(Node *list)
{
    while (list != NULL) {
        Node *p = list->next;
        // maybe:
        // free(list->data);
        free(list);
        list = p;
    }
}
```

A recursive solution:

```
void free_list(Node *list)
{
    if (list->next != NULL) {
        free_list(list->next);
    }

    // free(list->data);
    free(list);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. In my case the data points to something on the stack, so I don't need to free it then. Also you meant: but only 'after' you have taken care of the next element, right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the pointer itself is stored inside the struct. So when I free a node, the pointer variable is also freed, right?

Comment: @rgamber Yes, think of a struct as a chunk of memory. If you free it, everything inside it will be freed. Regardless of whether it is a pointer or not. If it's a pointer pointing to dynamically allocated memory, you have to free that memory *through* or *using* the pointer, but remember: `free()` doesn't do anything to the pointer itsef. It deallocates **the memory pointed to** by the pointer

Comment: This is not correct, or at least very misleading, as concerns `realloc`.  A call to `malloc` followed by N calls to `realloc` should be followed by exactly 1 call to `free()` in the user's code.

Comment: @MattPhillips Right, I wanted to be complete, whatever. I removed the reference to `realloc()` since it works differently. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you will need to also `free` the `data` member, and you have to do that before `free`ing `node`,

```
free(node->data);
free(node);
```

but you don't need to `free` `node->next`, since either you want to keep the remainder of the list, or you `free` the entire list, and then freeing the next is done in the next iteration of the loop.

You must not free `node->data` if that doesn't point to allocated (with `malloc` or the like) memory, but that is a rare situation.

Comment: Not freeing `node->data` when freeing `node` is not all that rare. For example, it could point to a string literal, or to a shared resource that must not be freed by a single node, but by a central authority that allocated it it.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is not a variable, it's a member of `struct node`. If you dynamically allocate `struct node` with a call to `malloc()`, you get a chunk of memory large enough to hold all the members of the struct. This obviously includes the storage for the `data` pointer, but not for the *contents* the pointer points to. Consequently, the storage for struct members must not be freed separately, it is enough to `free` the struct.

However, since `data` is itself a pointer, there is no telling where the memory it *points to* and whether this memory needs to be freed until we see how it is initialized.