# Clearing a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I came across this method to clear a binary search tree. The code is given in a textbook. Why must a node temp be created and deleted in the end? Why not delete the subroot instead of making it null?

```
void Binary_tree<Entry> :: recursive_clear(Binary_node<Entry> * &sub_root)
/* Post: The subtree rooted at sub_root is cleared. */
{
Binary_node<Entry> *temp = sub_root;
if (sub_root == NULL) return;
recursive_clear(sub_root->left);
recursive_clear(sub_root->right);
sub_root = NULL;
delete temp;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `sub_root` is passed by reference. This was asked **literally** ten minutes ago: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255235/using-free-on-a-c-struct/16255294#16255294)

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah but why store sub_root to temp since you pass sub_root->left or right and not sub_root .

Comment: @Armin Because there's the `sub_root = NULL;` statement.

Comment: Beats me. I can see no reason for the `temp` variable. If you switch the order of delete and assignment to NULL, I think the temp variable is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the standard way to delete dynamic memory is with delete, and [delete it's used with pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/).

Comment: Why not just do delete subroot instead of initializing a temp variable and delete it?

Comment: mmm, I think it will depend on the type of the left and right attribrutes. Can you post it here please? I just want to know if they are pointers or not

Comment: they must be... (sub_root->left), so I don't see a reason, like you, to create the temp var :S. The thing that puzzles me is the reference to pointer param